# How to get a Sharp Render when mixing foreground and background ViewLayers in EEVEE?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, compositing-nodes, viewlayers

The text has to appear sharp when blended with the background in the EEVEE compositor.
However even on switching the text blend mode to Alpha blend,setting Mix node blend to "ADD" and connecting both the alpha and Z depth values of the text to it ,the output still appears faded.

How to blend separate viewlayers to get a sharper render ?

[image]

[image: faded text]

[image: n eevee]

Comment: If you don't want it to be faded, don't RGB add.  RGB mix, with the alpha of the overlay as the mix factor.  That involves swapping your image inputs on the Mix node as you currently have your compositing set up (as you want the text overlay's alpha to determine the mix, with high alpha corresponding to full text image.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mix 'Add' mode is combining your renders without taking account of which of the two images is 'in-front' of the other. Blender needs to know how to combine the two images correctly.

Looking at your screenshot the Render Layers thumbnail shows you aren't using transparency in your renders (it's a solid background instead of checkered). The simplest solution is to enable Transparency :

[image: transparency]

Then once you have re-rendered your scene you should have an Alpha channel in your render results (the background should be transparent). You can then simply use the Alpha Over node instead of 'Mix' to produce the 'overlay' effect you want :

[image: alpha over]

An alternative (if the depth information is consistent between your render layers) is to use the Z-Combine node to combine two images based on depth (this allows you to have different elements from multiple render layers overlapping each other) :

[image: z-combine]

Comment: Thanks,never would have looked in Film for Transparency setting.